# Trying to copy data to a table with checkboxes, a form, and php

Tags: php, database, forms, checkbox

My webpage is pulling data from two tables - `applications` and `archiveapps` - and displays them using the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM applications";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "Lots of info, including some html thrown in for style."
```

I want users to be able to click a checkbox listed next to each row and then hit an "Archive Selections" button that then moves all the selected entries from the `applications` table to the `archiveapps` one.

So far I've tried  a form with it's code half in the echo above (so that a checkbox would go by each listed row from the `$sql` query) with the submit button outside (so that there would only be one "Archive Selections" button) but I'm sure this isn't proper syntax.

To actually move the data, I had this for the checkbox:

```
<form method='post' action=''><input type='checkbox' name='archname' value=".$row["charname"].">
```

(The above was inside an echo statement, so I assume it was able to pull the `$row["charname"]` no problem, but am unsure how to verify that.)

A little further down the page is the submit button and `</form>`.

And then I've got the function I want it to run when the submit button is clicked, to check if boxes have been selected and copy them into the `archiveapps` table. I'm sure there's something I'm missing here, probably in referencing what exactly is selected, and then copying that row's data to the other table... but honestly I just don't know enough about php to know what I'm missing.

```
if(!empty($_POST['archname'])) {
  foreach($_POST['archname'] as $check) {
    function archiveapp() {
      $sqli="INSERT INTO archiveapps SELECT * FROM applications";
      if ($conn->query($sqli) === TRUE) {
        echo "<i>Archived</i>";
      } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sqli . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }}}}
```

Most of this has just been gathered from google searches and kind of mushed together, so I'm sure there are a lot of things done wrong. Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Oh and my end goal is to copy the data to the `archiveapps` table and then delete it from the `applications` table, but for now I've just been focusing on the copying part, since I assume deleting a row will be fairly simple? Either way it's not the priority for this question.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're going to have multiple inputs with the same name, you need to do it like `name='archname[]'`

Comment: Thanks for that, I had forgotten!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tool like FireBug to see what you are actually posting to server. You have multiple checkboxes with the same name, so you are sending only 1 value (the last checked, I think).

You need to send all of them, so use brackets after the name:

```
<!-- this is just an example -->
<input type="checkbox" name="archname[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="archname[]" value="2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="archname[]" value="3" checked>
```

Then on PHP, inside `$_POST['archname']` you will get this:

```
Array(2, 3)
```

After this, you can do a `foreach(...)` loop like you are already doing, inserting only the ID you get from the `$_POST` variable:

```
foreach($_POST['archname'] as $id){
    $sqli = "INSERT INTO archiveapps (id) VALUES (".(int)$id.")";
}
```

Comment: I added in the brackets (I had forgotten about those!) but the rest is something a bit different than what I'm looking for. It looks like your suggestion inserts info about the checkbox selected into `archiveapps` but I want to copy an entire row from `applications` into `archiveapps` if the checkbox is selected.

Comment: so first you need to do a select then add all the missing columns on the insert.

Comment: Thanks!! Everything works fine now! At least it was until other people started using it - now stuff won't insert into the second table for some reason. Pfft.

Comment: There must've been some variable confusion or something - I renamed everything and it seems fine for now. Thanks again !